# Custom property on UIViewController like splitViewController or tabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have written a custom simple split view controller for purposes not fulfilled by UISplitView.

Now I want its child view controllers to access this custom split view just like we can access the `UISplitView` or `UITabBarController` or even `UINavigationController` directly regardless of complicated hierarchy of controllers.

For example, even if we use `UISplitView` inside `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` as one of the view controller of `tabBarController`, we always get appropriate controllers by using properties `splitViewController`, `tabBarController` & `navigationController` on actual controller classes. [It somehow traverses the hierarchy to get appropriate controller].

How can I create such a property to access my custom split view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way was to follow the Apple's way of accessing such properties. So, I created a category on `UIViewController` and added a read only property to it.

Then, I created the getter of this property in which I recursively traversed all the `parentViewController`s of current controller and returned the appropriate controller or nil otherwise.

```
@class CZSplitViewController;

@interface UIViewController (CZSplitViewContrller)

// Do not assign to this property
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CZSplitViewController *czSplitViewController;

@end
```

@implementation UIViewController (CZSplitViewContrller)

```
- (CZSplitViewController *)czSplitViewController
{
    return (CZSplitViewController *)[self recursivelyTraverseControllerParents:self];
}

- (UIViewController*) recursivelyTraverseControllerParents:(UIViewController*)controller
{
    if (!controller) return nil;
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:CZSplitViewController.class])
    {
        return controller;
    }

    return [self recursivelyTraverseControllerParents:controller.parentViewController];
}

@end
```

Comment: I knew I had misunderstood your question at some extent, now I got it.

Comment: well, your answer helped me in getting started :) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the question clearly, apology in advance.

**CustomUISplitViewController.m:**

```
-(void)showChildViewController:(UIViewController *)controller{
    controller.customSplitViewController = self;
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    //add view of controller, etc.
}
```

And you can write category on **UIViewController**:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CustomUISplitViewController *customSplitViewController;
```

Comment: I've gotten the idea from your code. when the custom splitViewController receives it's controllers, I could set the property (as you mentioned here) there. thanks .. (thumbs up)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a object of the controller whose view you wish to access.
2. Then in current view controller add the subview.

The above are the two steps which programmatically would be implemented as below :

```
A *a = [[A alloc]init];
[self.view addSubView: a.view];
```

Enjoy have fun. This is how i understood you question let me know if this is not what you need and explain question in brief.

Comment: wanted access to viewController not view.

Comment: as you can see you have the access to view controller, a is instance of the view controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the existing method and check the class, here is an example:

**SceneSplitViewController.h**

```
@interface SceneSplitViewController : UISplitViewController

@end

@interface UIViewController (SceneSplitViewController)

@property(strong, nonatomic, readonly) SceneSplitViewController *sceneSplitViewController;

@end
```

**SceneSplitViewController.m**

```
#import "SceneSplitViewController.h"

@implementation SceneSplitViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end

@implementation UIViewController (SceneSplitViewController)

- (SceneSplitViewController *)sceneSplitViewController{
    UISplitViewController *svc = self.splitViewController;
    if([svc isKindOfClass:SceneSplitViewController.class]){
        return (SceneSplitViewController *)svc;
    }
    return svc.sceneSplitViewController;
}

@end
```